# Python Pandas convert month/year dataframe with one column to dataframe where each row is one year

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-wrangling

Given a Pandas dataframe of the form

```
January-2021,0.294 
February-2021,0.252 
March-2021,0.199 
...
January-2022,0.384 
February-2022,0.333 
March-2022,0.271 
...
```

how do I transform it to a dataframe with 12 columns, one for each month, so it looks like

```
year,January,February,March,...
2021,0.294,0.252,0.199,...
2022,0.384,0.333,0.271,...
```

Comment: Your input is unclear, do you have 1 or 2 columns? What are the header(s)?

Comment: Two columns, as shown, with the first column being a month-year pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) then use [`pd.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html).

```
# January-2021, ... exists in 'Date' column.
df[['Month', 'Year']] = pd.DataFrame(df['Date'].str.split('-').to_list())

# 0.294, ... exists in 'Value' column
df_new = df.pivot(index='Year', columns='Month', values='Value')

print(df_new)
```

Output:

```
Month  February  January  March
Year                           
2021      0.252    0.294  0.199
2022      0.333    0.384  0.271
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
# `month-year` is name of date column
dates = df['month-year'].str.extract('(?P<month>\w+)-(?P<year>\d+)')

# `data` is name of data column
pd.crosstab(dates['year'], dates['month'], df['data'], aggfunc='first')
```

Output:

```
month  February  January  March
year                           
2021      0.252    0.294  0.199
2022      0.333    0.384  0.271
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `pivot` to get the desired output.

````
```
# prepare dataframe
   data = [('January-2021',0.294), ('February-2021',0.252), ('March-2021',0.199), 
           ('January-2022',0.384), ('February-2022',0.333), ('March-2022',0.271) ]
   df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['date', 'val'])

   # extract month and year
   df['month'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.split('-')[0])
   df['year'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.split('-')[1])
   df.drop(['date'], axis=1, inplace=True)

   # pivoting the dataframe
   df = df.pivot(index='year', columns='month')

   # rename the columns
   df.columns = [c[1] for c in df.columns]
   df = df.reset_index()
```
````

At the end you will the the following result:

[image]